# Auto add data to another model database table after create from another model form in rubyonrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please I am new to Rails. I want to populate a model database table from another model form. I have a customer model and form and I want to save the form data into the customer database table and also add data to another customer account database table. The customer fields are

Name,
Address,
Phone,
Current_balance,
Outstanding_balance.

**Customer account fields,**
customer name,
transaction date,
balance,
mode of payment

Below is my code but I cannot seem to solve the problem.

**Customer model**

class Customer < ApplicationRecord

```
after_create :add_customer_account 

has_many :customer_accounts 

def add_customer_account
  b= CustomerAccount.new
  b.transaction_date = Customer.created_at
  b.balance = Customer.current_balance.to_i - Customer.outstanding_balance.to_i
  b.customer_id = Customer.id
  b.invoice = "0"
  b.create
end
```

end

**Customer Account model**

class CustomerAccount < ApplicationRecord

```
belongs_to :customer
```

end

What how do I get it done

Comment: It is not getting created. From my terminal I get transaction rolledback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of after_create callback.

Just try to put the method call inside the if @customer.save inside the create action.

```
  if @customer.save
    add_customer_account       <---------
    format.html {render ..... blabla
  else
    ...
  end
```

The second thing that i see is that you're putting this code inside the Model, try to keep the business logic inside the controller.

Try to define the add_customer_account under private inside the customers_controller, and then call it as i mentioned before.

> Use the method from the **Jhumur Chatterjee** and put a byebug just before the b.save! action. Then in the console you can just do ***b.errors.messages***

Comment: Thanks Toni Saez valls and Jhumur Chatterjee. I was able to get it done using your process. I added the add_customer_account class in the customer controller and both database table get populated.

Comment: Great to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:

```
# app/models/customer.rb

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :add_customer_account 

  has_many :customer_accounts 

  def add_customer_account
    b = customer_accounts.new
    b.transaction_date = self.created_at
    b.balance = self.balance
    b.invoice = "0"
    b.save!
  end

  def balance
    (current_balance - outstanding_balance).to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks jhumur Chatterjee. I will try this and give response.

Comment: Hello jhumur Chatterjee, thanks once again. after adding the the code, the formis not getting added to the database. From the terminal, i see transaction rollback. I think the process is not working. Is there a better way to do this? Please i need help